# Free XML formatter (indent) tool on Mac?

Tags: xml, macos, editor

Need a tool that can format the xml in human readable format on Mac!

Comment: This would be slightly more on-topic for Superuser, and far more on-topic for Software Recommendations SE. It is off-topic here (for future reference of anyone looking to ask something similar).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest you install XMLLint which the best solution to view pretty formatted XML (included in LibXML package.

Comment: I suggest you don't install `xmllint`, as it comes with Mac OS X.

Comment: "xmllint <file> --pretty 1"   works flawlessly!

Answer (score 16):

I use TextWrangler (free) together with a text filter which uses xmllint. Download it here: http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/download.html

After you have it, create a new file and save it with a name like tidy.sh under `~/Library/Application Support/TextWrangler/Text Filters`. Write the following in the file and save it:

```
#!/bin/sh
XMLLINT_INDENT=$'\t' xmllint --format --encode utf-8 -
```

The above should also work for BBEdit 11.  For versions of TextWrangler < 4.0 or BBEdit < 11, this script should be slightly different:

```
#!/bin/sh
xmllint "$*" | XMLLINT_INDENT=$'\t' xmllint --format --encode utf-8 -
```

Then you'll be able to apply this from the Text menu > Apply Text Filter > tidy
To make it even easier, you can bind a shortcut to this.
Go to Window > Palettes > Text Filters. You will see your tidy filter there. Select and hit "Set Key..." and choose a combination that suits you (I use alt+cmd+x).

Comment: I can't actually get that script to work (or variations on it) in textwranger. But it works as just a shell script with `$1` in place of the `"$*"`. Sorry for the necro-threading but I figured this might be a help for someone else in my situation.

Answer (score -1):

Just started today to use Serna: http://www.serna-xmleditor.com

Comment: Downvoting for a link posted in 2011 doesn't seem fair :) Anyway, here's the updated link: http://www.serna-xmleditor.com/